# How do I call the current class type in typescript with inheritence

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What type can I specify as the return type of the `fromObject` method?

```
class Entity {
    public toObject(): QueryRow {
        throw new Error('This method has to be overriden and implemented');
    }
    // This method is supposed to return a value with the type of the current class
    public static fromObject(object: QueryRow): ??? {
        throw new Error(
            'This method has to be overridden and implemented' + object
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: So your child classes can return different types when overriding the method? Could you add a base class that all implementations use?

Comment: There's no polymorphic `this` type for static members, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863, nor are there abstract static members, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516.  Any workaround will be hard to use (you can kind of use generics to do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBjXVN) but the subclass implementations will be obnoxious like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbA93N)).  Maybe you should make a class factory instead like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAj3PW)? Not sure.  Let me know what you want to see here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, but it looks like this:

```typescript
public static fromObject<T extends typeof Entity>(this: T, object: QueryRow): InstanceType<T> {
```

Then when you do (for instance):

```typescript
class ThingyEntity extends Entity {
    // ...implement `fromObject`
}
// ...
const te = ThingyEntity.fromObject(someQueryRowObject);
```

...`te` is of type `ThingyEntity`.

That works because in JavaScript (and TypeScript), in a static method `this` is set by how it's called (it will refer to `Entity` [the constructor function type] if you do `Entity.staticMethod()`, but to `ThingyEntity` if you do `ThingyEntity.staticMethod()`). So we capitalize on that by using a TypeScript `this` type annotation (the [`this` pseudo-parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters)) and saying it'll have the type `T`, which extends `typeof Entity` (the constructor function type). TypeScript infers the type from the call, and we use `InstanceType<T>` to get the type you want as the result.

Here's a complete example with a stand-in `QueryRow` type:

```typescript
interface QueryRow {
    something: number;
}

class Entity {
    public toObject(): QueryRow {
        throw new Error('This method has to be overriden and implemented');
    }

    // This method is supposed to return a value with the type of the current class
    public static fromObject<T extends typeof Entity>(this: T, object: QueryRow): InstanceType<T> {
        throw new Error('This method has to be overridden and implemented');
    }
}

class ThingyEntity extends Entity {
    public static fromObject<T extends typeof ThingyEntity>(this: T, object: QueryRow): InstanceType<T> {
        const result = new ThingyEntity() as InstanceType<T>; // Unfortunately, AFAICT the type assertion is necessary
        // ...
        return result;;
    }
}
const someQueryRowObject = {something: 42};
const e = Entity.fromObject(someQueryRowObject);
//    ^? const e = Entity

const te = ThingyEntity.fromObject(someQueryRowObject);
//    ^? const te = ThingyEntity
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdoE8BKB7Ad2QG8AoZC5AZzwFsIwALUAcwC5kR1aAjaAblIBfUqQQAbOFSrIAouGBgsJcpQAO6HuOAJkYPAHkeAKwgIwACgCUHDNnxEylZ3sZRCnCEVlR3UCwDkACrMMvRMeAAmyIxSenjIfMh4AG7QUMCRECDIcCDRwLRq4hD04BCRAVaCziKqFAD0DcghwGEMjFHIbdToamp4VBXxyFAM6FA5cMgpcOKYyASKjK4oSmooeDCryAgTY+C7ktL1yBpaOtRgcGCXMO60RqbmADxByBAAHpD5MusQWzkCiUAD4LEw2hwggAaZImMxgWyYKC4Qg2ZAASRAVGuICQQSwGzeIJULkoTHcRBAXjkvjw-mCoWQ4U60VifwSSVS6UyWSm+W6RRKZUglWqpxEdQkUhkrRALCw8luSg+32ykRkSsUyic6k02l0OJudweTwRb1VPw1ekJAO2coVWtB4NCUNheHh5iR9jRHCxRrxEAJRKCJN1ZIQeGxYFGECo6HEMYAvJ4iA7FcCsNZcjJ-bj8bbifxkE1kABVEAwelgdAgG4QcRYWEAQQAYs2MQBhd5MNa2nNDKC3KPdGTUpDSOAo07OUsAOgXM8oYxrk1j8cT-BqlElYijOOodAgdhRDjN5mQKeINBZrA4ABYAExCQSR6MfS9A5VYOf3Ojnywb2PZFUQIADxVLSgAD0AH5RDfA9IE-dMnR-P9Hk9QCjxPUDwMESCKFg0ggA)

Comment: *(I had a fairly basic error in the answer. Hit refresh to see the corrected version.)*